# Discord.js Bot getting offline without any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i've created bot for analyze PUBG stats and set up specific role based on stats.
Last time i added check for casual mode, bot is checking last 25games of player and check if there were more than 85% bots. On small group of players it worked good but know i'm caching up around 200players and bot just going offline without any errors. Im using premium account on replit.com to keep him 24h up, stoping and starting again fixes the problem till next loop. Im not running out the session limits from disocrd
Discord.js debug don't show errors.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTTdi.png)

```
Dicord_Bot.on("debug", (e) => console.log(e))



exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  var membersArray = message.guild.members.cache;
  const insertInto = bot.dbsql2.prepare('INSERT INTO testo(nickname, pubg_id, match_id , assists, damageDealt, headshotKills, kills, win) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
  for (let [snowflake, guildMember] of membersArray) {
    if (guildMember.user.bot) {
      continue;
    }
    var nickname = guildMember.nickname;
    if (!nickname)
      nickname = guildMember.user.username;
    console.log("Sprawdzam " + nickname);
    var matchesList = bot.pubgAPI.getPlayerMatchesList(bot, nickname);
    var pubgID = bot.pubgAPI.getPlayerID(bot, nickname);
    if(pubgID === 0 || pubgID === -1) {
      continue;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
      var participants = 0;
      var bots = 0;
      var players = 0;
      var lastStats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
      if (matchesList[i] === undefined) {
        console.log("Brak meczu");
        continue;
      }
      var matchStats = bot.pubgAPI.getMatchStats(bot, matchesList[i].id)
      if (matchStats === undefined) {
        console.log("Brak stat");
        continue;
      }
      if (matchStats.data === undefined) {
        console.log("Brak daty");
        continue;
      }
      if (matchStats.data.attributes === undefined) {
        console.log("Brak atrybutow");
        continue;
      }
      if (matchStats.data.attributes.stats === undefined) {
        console.log("Brak statow");
        continue;
      }
      if (matchStats.data.attributes.gameMode === "squad" && matchStats.data.attributes.matchType === "official") {
        for (let j = 0; j < matchStats.included.length; j++) {
          if (matchStats.included[j] === undefined) {
            continue;
          }
          if (matchStats.included[j].attributes === undefined) {
            continue;
          }
          if (matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats === undefined) {
            continue;
          }
          if (matchStats.included[j].type === "participant") {
            participants++;
            if (matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.playerId.includes("ai.")) {
              bots++;
            }
            else {
              players++;
            }
          }
          if (matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.playerId === pubgID) {
            lastStats[0] += matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.assists
            lastStats[1] += matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.damageDealt
            lastStats[2] += matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.headshotKills
            lastStats[3] += matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.kills
            if (matchStats.included[j].attributes.stats.winPlace === 1) {
              lastStats[6] += 1
            }
            else {
              lastStats[4] += 1
            }
            lastStats[5] += 1
          }
        }
        if (((bots / participants) >= 0.50)){
          var returnMessage = "**" + nickname + "**" + " miał " + ((bots / participants) * 100).toFixed(2) + "% botów.";
          returnMessage += "\n**Usuwamy ze statystyk:**";
          returnMessage += "\nDamage:" + lastStats[1].toFixed(2)
          returnMessage += "\nAsysty:" + lastStats[0]
          returnMessage += "\nHeadshoty:" + lastStats[2]
          returnMessage += "\nKille:" + lastStats[3]
          if (lastStats[6] != 0) {
            returnMessage += "\nWin:1"
          }
          bot.channels.cache.get("952186890499530792").send(returnMessage);
          insertInto.run(nickname,pubgID,matchesList[i].id,lastStats[0],lastStats[1],lastStats[2],lastStats[3],lastStats[6])
        }
      }
      var sleep1 = await bot.sleepFor(10);
    }
    var sleep = await bot.sleepFor(1000)
  }
}
exports.help = {
  name: "test",
  channel: "952186890499530792",
  members: ["248165905119313948"]
}
```